# Publish story to news feed using facebooker [Ruby]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebooker

I followed the tutorial here http://yardoc.org/docs/mmangino-facebooker/Facebooker/User#publish_story-instance_method
using

```
@user.publish_to(@user, :message => 'hello world')
```

Where `@user` is an instance of `Facebooker::User`.

This method call causes the application to error out. Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by "error out"? We can't help you unless you tell us what error you're getting.

Comment: I know it's a bit vague. I have my application running in a production environment so the error isn't output. 
Is there some other code I need, ie does the user need to give permission to receive notifications?

Comment: If your app isn't really in production you can put into your facebook app settings your development url (e.g. http://localhost:3000).

Second: you can tail the production log and tell us (and yourself first) the error.

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to tail the log file. Apparently Facebook deprecated the api method "facebook.feed.publishActionOfUser". Anyone know of any _up_to_date_ tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution http://gist.github.com/267412

Comment: Hey can you please update with the exact steps you took to get this working.  I am also trying to do this.  Thanks.

Comment: facebooker_publisher.rb goes in the lib folder. try the gist and let me know where you run into a wall.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
http://groups.google.com/group/facebooker/browse_thread/thread/2300ee8a38a064dc